# Lucene multi index search

Tags: c#, .net, search, lucene, lucene.net

So i have created ~10 indexes, based on categories and i made everything work with category search.
But know i need to create a function that returns ALL results based on search, that means from all ~10 indexes, and scored and rated as if it would be one index.

How do you do that ?
Tried with objects like MultiSearcher did not worked for me.
So how do you put TopDocs index results into some kind of collection that could be scored and looped through ?
Also tried TopDocsCollector but then i cant initiate it or add to it new score docs from second searcher.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using several indexes instead of one big index where category is just a field your filter on?

Comment: Yeah maybe should of done that, but now already done like this... thought that it will be faster to have few smaller ones, since 95% of functionality and searches are on specific categories, but having now problems with get all results regarding it.. so is it possible ?

Comment: I agree that reworking it to use the same index is likely the best approach here, but if your stuck with it, creating a `MultiSearcher` or (better yet) a `MultiReader` would be the right way to go about it.  Can you show what you have tried, and what went wrong?